# box shadow different in IE than in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

everyone know that box shadow can render completely different in IE than in chrome or Firefox (it's unbelievable for me). my question is how you handle this situation ? because the design can completely change in some case ... most of the time the box shadow on IE is little thin than on Chrome/Firefox. is their any java-script plugin that can automatically on IE increase a little the box shadow ?

Comment: The only way for 3 people to not use their voice telling your story is for you to give them all a recording of your own voice telling the story :) e.g. jpg, gif etc.

Comment: Internet Explorer has supported `box-shadow` for a while now. What exactly is different?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep this in mind: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

To clarify: you might want to rethink whether it really is that important that shadows are exactly the same width in every browser. It might not provide that different a feel, whereas little hacks like stating a width other than the desired one because it appears to be what you want in a specific browser on a specific operating system on specific hardware might have undesirable effects in setups that you're unable to test.

Comment: If you can't convince them by telling teaching how this will lead to the page actually looking broken for customers, then you're screwed already.

Comment: I strongly disagree. I do think explaining and teaching is important, but I also think that a web page should look the same on every browser, within the limitations of size (while using responsive design) and accessibility theme. Of course, if someone want to override my CSS for some reason I have no control over it, but there is no reason why different browsers would render a web page differently, given both support all the CSS styles and font and media formats one uses.

Comment: From the W3 CSS standard: "7.1.2. Blurring Shadow Edges

A non-zero blur radius indicates that the resulting shadow should be blurred, such as by a Gaussian filter. The exact algorithm is not defined; however the resulting shadow must approximate (with each pixel being within 5% of its expected value) the image that would be generated by applying to the shadow a Gaussian blur with a standard deviation equal to half the blur radius". This means that all shadow rendering should look almost the same.

Comment: Then we disagree on that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

Thats:

```
box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];
```

The horizontal offset (required) of the shadow, positive means the shadow will be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on the left of the box.

The vertical offset (required) of the shadow, a negative one means the box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow will be below the box.

The blur radius (required), if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp, the higher the number, the more blurred it will be, and the further out the shadow will extend. For instance a shadow with 5px of horizontal offset that also has a 5px blur radius will be 10px of total shadow.

The spread radius (optional), positive values increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur).

Color (required) - takes any color value, like hex, named, rgba or hsla. If the color value is omitted, box shadows are drawn in the foreground color (text color). But be aware, older WebKit browsers (pre Chrome 20 and Safari 6) ignore the rule when color is omitted.

Using a semi-transparent color like rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) is most common, and a nice effect, as it doesn't completely/opaquely cover what it's over, but allows what's underneath to show through a bit, like a real shadow.

---

**Internet Explorer (8 and down) Box Shadow**

You need an extra element, but it's do-able with filter.

```
<div class="shadow1">
  <div class="content">
    Box-shadowed element
  </div>
</div>

.shadow1 {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(68,68,68); /* Needed for IEs */

  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
  zoom: 1;
}

.shadow1 .content {
  position: relative; /* This protects the inner element from being blurred */
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

source : [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

Comment: Did you literally just copy and paste much of Chris' article?

Comment: @JonathanSampson yes... thats why I mentioned the source with link there at the bottom of the answer... I hope thats fair enough, correct and update me if thats not the right way to do.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) for box shadow to work in IE.